How does the phidl library change units from microns to nanometers?
I'm new to this library, Phidl and I need to understand how this library changes units from microns to nanometers. My problem statement is I need to create 9 grids and each grid is 40x40 circles. The diameter of circles should be 50 nm, 100 nm, 200 nm, 250 nm, 300 nm, 500 nm, 1000nm, 2000nm etc. now i need to vary the pitch (distance between center of 2  circles) such that for the pitch between two 100 nm circles it is 200 nm i.e double the size of the diameter
'''
D_f = dl.Device()
D_1 = dl.Device()

# Define initial pitch size
pitch_size = 10

for i in range(0, 40):
    for j in range(0, 40):
        # Create circle
        D_1 = pg.circle(radius=0.5, angle_resolution=2.5, layer=0)
        
        # Adjust circle position based on pitch size
        D_1.x = i
        D_1.y = 4+j
        
        # Add circle to container (assuming D_f is the container)
        D_f << D_1

D_f.x=0
D_f.y=0

qp(D_f)

D = pg.basic_die(
              size = (500, 500), # Size of die
              street_width = 10,   # Width of corner marks for die-sawing
              street_length = 50, # Length of corner marks for die-sawing
              die_name = '1 µm',  # Label text
              text_size = 20,      # Label text size
              text_location = 'S', # Label text compass location e.g. 'S', 'SE', 'SW'
              layer = 0,
              draw_bbox = False,
              bbox_layer = 9,
              )
qp(D) # quickplot the geometry

D_f << D
qp(D_f)
 
D_f.x=0
D_f.y=0

D_f1 << D_f
qp(D_f1)

D_f.write_gds('test.gds')

'''

Internally, phidl represents all sizes just as floating point (decimal) values of 64-bit precision--there's no conversion to microns/nanometers at all.  When you save to .gds, however, you have the option of setting the database unit that rounds the number to the desired precision.  For example, I may want the radius of 15.12345 to correspond to "15.12345 microns, rounded to the nearest nanometer -> the .gds saves the value 15.123.  See the write_gds() documentation
As far as spacing your circles, it looks like you're on the right track. From what I can tell about your code, you're trying to add more space between the circles?  One major thing to note:  the 50 nm circle you're trying to specify should have a radius of 0.025 (to give a diameter of 0.050 um = 50 nm)
